# Selenium - Use text string in several TestNG @Test-annotations

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a text string tag i grab with getText.
Then i want to use that string in another @Test

I have tried to put it in @BeforeSuite but can't make that to work either?

Can you please assist...:)

```html
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class values_test {

    static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        driver = new HandelDriver().getDriver("CHROME");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://chercher.tech/selenium-webdriver-sample");

    }


    @Test (priority = 100)
     public void GetText() throws IOException {
        // fetches text from the element and stores it in text
        String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='breadcrumb-item active update']")).getText();
        System.out.println("Text String is : "+ text);
    }


    @Test (priority = 101)
    public void PasteText() throws IOException {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id=\"exampleInputEmail1\"]")).sendKeys(text);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your GetText() method actually is not a test method, but a utility method. It can be a part of another package, but certainly does need to have a @Test annotation. You can still call it's logic in the BeforeTest method.

Either way, if you want to use this string in multiple tests, you need a reference to it, i.e. the `value_test` class should have a `String text` field. I would also advise using a more descriptive variable name than "text".

You can still call it in the BeforeTest set up, but now you'll have where to store the fetched value.

Along the lines of:

```java
public class values_test {

    static WebDriver driver;
    static String text;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        driver = new HandelDriver().getDriver("CHROME");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://chercher.tech/selenium-webdriver-sample");
        GetText();
    }

    public void GetText() throws IOException {
        text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='breadcrumb-item active update']")).getText();
        System.out.println("Text String is : "+ text);
    }
     
    @Test (priority = 101)
    public void CanPasteTextInFirstEmailField() throws IOException {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id=\"exampleInputEmail1\"]")).sendKeys(text);
    }

    @Test (priority = 102)
    public void CanPasteTextInSecondEmailField() throws IOException {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id=\"exampleInputEmail2\"]")).sendKeys(text);
    }
```

PS Each test should have a clear outcome, so you unequivocally know the results of a test case. Be sure to read up on Asserts, TestNG offers loads of possibilities.

PPS The names of tests should also be more descriptive and should de really precise on what it is testing.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply! I’m learning, and now  i’m a step forward in how to use this.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If you are happy with the response it would be nice if you could mark the answer as accepted by clicking the green check mark.